# Nmake - compiling all source files in all subfolders

Tags: nmake, subdirectory

I want to create a generic nmake file that can be used for multiple projects with minimal changes to the .mak file. I want it to compile all of the source files (c/cpp) in a folder as well as all of the source files in all subfolders. I'm not sure if it's possible to use wildcards for directory names or how I would iteratively traverse multiple directory levels. Is this possible using nmake?

Comment: Sad to see this question not having received all the love it deserves... :)

Answer (score -2):

You'd better try makecc, CMake or something similar.